# Talking to spdy server with netty client

Tags: netty, spdy

I want talk to a spdy/2 server in android app with netty.

When googled this question, only got the way to build a netty spdy server.

Does someone have a example of a netty spdy client?

Answer (score 0):

`SpdyFrameEncoder` and `SpdyFrameDecoder` can be used for encoding and decoding an SPDY frame, which applies both to clients and to servers.  However, `SpdySessionHandler` is for server only, and thus you have only very basic construct at your hand.  As far as I know, no one in the community attempted to write a client side SPDY session handler.

Answer (score 0):

I just sent a pull request with an example that should help you:
https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/2150

It uses SPDY 3.1, but it shouldn't be hard to adapt to 2.